# How to do Cache Sizing?

Tags: ignite, gridgain, distributed-caching, apacheignite

Using Ignite 2.15, i am trying to do some cache sizing. Do we have any documents to do sizing activity?

I found an old document https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/capacity-planning

Is this still relevant, in the newer documentation i don't see the references to the above document.

Also even in this document, what is the an overhead of one cache minus the data. I was doing some basic tests where i used the example dataregion configuration file and simply added caches with no data and recorded some memory numbers off my mac.

Below are the number's i see,

| Config | Memory | Real | Private | Compressed | Threads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No Caches | 365.4 MB | 343.4 MB | 88.0 MB | 45.1 MB | 99 |
| 5 Caches | 456.5 MB | 442.9 MB | 388.3 MB | 36.4 MB | 102 |
| 10 Caches | 625.7 MB | 422.9 MB | 366.1 MB | 225.4 MB | 108 |
| 15 Caches | 687.2 MB | 444.7 MB | 388.9 MB | 264.8 MB | 108 |
| 20 Caches | 687.2 MB | 444.7 MB | 388.9 MB | 264.8 MB | 108 |
| 40 Caches | 971.5 MB | 516.4 MB | 457.7 MB | 476.9 MB | 108 |

So roughly i see ~ 15-20MB per cache. Is this understanding accurate? Any way to reduce this internal memory footprint?

Below are the dataregion and cache configs. Pretty straight forward off the examples configs,

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <!--
                Default memory region that grows endlessly. A cache is bound to this memory region
                unless it sets another one in its CacheConfiguration.
            -->
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="Default_Non_Persistent_Region"/>
                    <!-- 15 MB initial memory region with disabled eviction -->
                    <property name="initialSize" value="#{15 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                     <!-- 400 MB max memory region -->
                    <property name="maxSize" value="#{400 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

One cache config, other are more of this only the name would change,

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="cache1"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
            </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the capacity planning page went to. You can see [one on the GridGain side](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/capacity-planning). You can use things like cache groups -- which allow tables to share some of their metadata -- to reduce the memory used.

Comment: Yes, i did read about that. But it also talks about the performance impact for 'get' ops or cases where 'indexes' come into play (queries). Any idea how much of a performance drop this could be?